# JavaFx: Update position every frame

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently writing a board game in JavaFx. For that, I have a class `Board` which contains a list of `Field`. A `Field` has just a `y` and an `x` value as a position. In the `start`-Method of my application I create an object of the board game which creates in its constructor some fields and adds it to the list. Now I get the field-list from the boardgame, iterate over it and then draw a circle on the given position.

Now my question: How do I get to change the coordinates where the circle is drawn at runtime for moving/animating the field? Is there a way to "link" my field object coordinates to the drawn circle (maybe extending the class, so that it is drawable directly or so) or do I have to delete all Elements out of the stage and add new circles with the new position of my fields?

The field might be later a bit more complex (graphic, text, EventListner etc.) So the solution should be valid not only for a shape.

Here is the relevant code:

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    int windowWidth = 1000;
    int windowHeight = 1000;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        window = primaryStage;

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(button1);

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(group, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        scene1.setFill(Color.rgb(100,100,100, 0.2));

        Board board = new Board();

        for (Field f : board.getFields()) {
            //Make circles out of the fields
            Circle circle = new Circle(calculatePercentageX(f.getXPos()), calculatePercentageY(f.getYPos()), 20, Color.RED);
            group.getChildren().add(circle);
        }

        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public int calculatePercentageX(int xPx) {
        System.out.println(xPx + " und " + windowWidth + " und " + 100);
        return (int)Math.round(windowWidth/100*xPx);
    }

    public int calculatePercentageY(int yPx) {
        return (int)Math.round(windowHeight/100*yPx);
    }
}
```

`Board.java`

```
public class Board {
    List<Field> fields = new LinkedList<>();

    public Board() {

        //generate fields (id, xPos, yPos)
        fields.add(new Field(0, 10, 10));
        fields.add(new Field(1, 20, 20));
        fields.add(new Field(2, 40, 30));
        fields.add(new Field(3, 40, 60));
        fields.add(new Field(4, 60, 20));
    }

    public List<Field> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

`Field.java`

```
public class Field {
    protected int id = 0;
    protected int xPos = 0;
    protected int yPos = 0;

    public Field(int id, int xPos, int yPos){
        this.id = id;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public int getXPos(){
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getYPos(){
        return yPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `AnimationTimer`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: thanks for your suggestion. I will look into it and present my result.

Comment: My final solution is now to use the X and Y property of the container and bind it to the X and Y property of my field object. This way I can control the position of the container through changing the values of my field object. This makes it much more easier because all the logic is in my class.